# RoR Beginner Routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I've created a DB and a table within that DB called genre.

Now when I try to connect to this using the URL, I get the following error message:

Routing Error

No route matches "/genre" with {:method=>:get}

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: The routes have nothing to do with the db you are using. Did you define the route in `config/routes.rb`. Default routed added by `script/generate scaffold Genre` will be pluralized, so you should try `/genres`

Comment: You do not mention if you did you define the route in your config/routes.rb file. Can you provide a cut&paste of the content of routes.rb?

Comment: Thanks for your response jens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that /genre should be /genres

I just wrote an app from scratch to work with genres and this is my routes file:

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
  map.resources :genres

  # these last two lines should go away but I left them in
  # here because my example worked as is.
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
end
```

So you would want to make sure that you are using the pural form of the noun genre.

Also `rake routes` is a great way to see what your routes are setup as.

Comment: Beware `connect ':controller/:action/:id'`, it makes all your controller methods accessible via `GET` requests - `resources` for restful routes is all you really need there ^.^

Comment: Yes good point! I left them in my example because the example worked in that state. WANNABE, you'll want to remove those entries before you go to production.

Comment: At last its doing something but now I'll getting this error - DOH! I've looked it up across the web and it seems to be a problem with an empty index.html.erb file?

NameError in GenresController#index

uninitialized constant GenresController
RAILS_ROOT: C:/Users/Will/Desktop/INSTAN~1/rails_apps/talewiki

Comment: WANNABE, if you post your email here, I will send you the code that I used to get this to work.

Answer (score 2):

As @Jens Fahnenbruck said, you need to set up your route in `config/routes.rb`.

If you want to find out what routes exist on your app, type `rake routes` into the command line.

Comment: About the Map Routes, I have no : map.resources :genres line in the code, is this required?

I have everything else.

Comment: the map.connect lines in my example would catch your /genres routes but you really need to have map.resources :genres in there so you can make use of the genres path variables like `link_to new_genre`

Comment: check your routes with `rake routes`. If /genres isn't there, you need to adjust your `routes.rb` file - yes, you probably need to add `map.resources :genres`, but there are several ways of achieving what you want. Check out the top few screencasts in this search: http://railscasts.com/episodes?search=route